# Pentaho PDI - Reading data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have installed Pentaho Data Integration version (ce-5.0.1.A-stable) in my machine and I am trying to retrive information from MongoDB using PDI. I have created a transformation with Mongo Input step. Now when I try to configure my MongoDB connection details, I couldnt find any explicit connection Type for MongoDB. Could someone please advise on how to configure MongoDB datasource in Pentaho.

[image]
I have referred most of the Pentaho-MongoDb docs, but none of the solution works out.

Also, I have tried performing below steps as mentioned in Pentaho Official site, but still I couldnt find any connection Type for MongoDB

1- Move the following folder out of the data-integration folder structure:
data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin

2- Move the following files out of the data-integration folder structure if they exist:
data-integration/libext/JDBC/pentaho-hadoop-hive-jdbc-shim-1.3.0.jar
data-integration/libext/JDBC/pentaho-hadoop-hive-jdbc-shim-1.3.1.jar
data-integration/libext/JDBC/pentaho-hadoop-hive-jdbc-shim-1.3.2.jar

3- Unzip the file pentaho-big-data-plugin-shimtastic-1.3.3.1.zip from the data-integration/plugins folder.

4- Optionally, remove irrelevant folders under data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations.

5- Copy the file pentaho-hadoop-hive-jdbc-shim-1.3.3.jar into the folder 
data-integration/libext/JDBC

6- Unzip the file pentaho-instaview-templates-shimtastic-1.3.3.zip to the following directory to
    data-integration/plugins/spoon/agile-bi/platform/pentaho-solutions/system/instaview/templates/Big Data

Any help is really appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho doesnot have a specific database connection for MongodB. So you will not find it in the Database Connection viewer. The way to connect to Mongodb is to use **Mongodb Input** step in PDI. There you will find the connection details section *(configure credentials)*. You can then connect **JSON Input** step to read the results of your mongodb output. Check the below screenshot:

[image]

You can also read it from the Pentaho Wiki in [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Read+Data+From+MongoDB). Though the documentation seems to be slightly old, but it is the exact process to do it.

On a note you don't need Bigdata shims to connect to mongodb. It seems you have configured the hadoop-hive shims. It not required in here.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Info.